# Activate global minor modes from use-package

Tags: use-package

I used `global-company-mode` from my `.emacs` like this:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
```

Now I’m trying to move to `use-package`, like this:

```
(use-package company
  :config
  (global-company-mode))
```

Now if I check with <kbd>C-h m</kbd>, `company-mode` is said to be active, but it’s not listed on my modeline (I don’t use anything that would hide it). And it actually works, as I get the `company` popup, when I start typing a function or variable name.

`whitespace-mode` is much worse, though:

```
(use-package whitespace
  :ensure t  ;; I also tried without this line
  :config
    (global-whitespace-mode)
  :bind
  (([f10] . whitespace-mode)
   ([(shift f10)] . global-whitespace-mode)))
```

Now `WS` doesn’t appear on my modeline as expected (again, I don’t hide anything) and I cannot see its effects like the end-of-line marker `$` characters, and it’s not even listed when I press <kbd>C-h m</kbd>. But when I press <kbd>shift f10</kbd>, it says

```
Global Whitespace mode disabled
```

and when I press it again, I get the message that it got enabled, and I can also see the effects in all my buffers (and in <kbd>C-h m</kbd>).

What am I missing?

**Edit**: I just realised that `diminish` is actually installed as a dependency (I’m trying to figure out what pulled it in). However, `diminished-mode-alist` is `nil`, so I don’t think that’s the reason of mode names not displaying in my mode line (correct me if I’m wrong).

**Edit2**: deferring loading the `diminish` package solved the `company` problem, but the `whitespace` related one still persists.

Comment: that is strange. Try putting this in your `.emacs` and see if `company-mode` is not appearing in mode-line :- `(use-package diminish :defer t)`. You'd have to restart emacs after you modify `.emacs`

Comment: that solved the company-related problem, but the whitespace thing still remains…

Comment: how about enabling `whitespace-mode` like so :- `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'whitespace-mode)` ?

Comment: I actually used `after-init-hook` before switching to `use-package`; it worked fine. The strange thing here is that the `global-whitespace-mode` is `t`, yet, its effects are not visible unless I toggle it twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know why `company-mode` is getting diminished, but I think I know what's going on with `whitespace-mode`.  Your block

```el
(use-package whitespace
  :ensure t  ;; I also tried without this line
  :config
    (global-whitespace-mode)
  :bind
  (([f10] . whitespace-mode)
   ([(shift f10)] . global-whitespace-mode)))
```

will automatically defer loading the `whitespace` package because it includes a `:bind`.  So nothing happens until you press <kbd>S-<f10></kbd>, at which time the package gets loaded, your `:config` block runs, and `global-whitespace-mode` is enabled.  Then your keypress is processed, and the mode is promptly disabled again.  There are three solutions that occur to me:

1. You could change your `:config` into an `:init` and rely on the fact that `global-whitespace-mode` is autoloaded to load the package for you.
2. You could add a `:demand t` line, to cancel `:bind`'s deferment.
3. You could add `:defer N`, where `N` is an integer.  This will trigger loading whenver Emacs is idle for `N` seconds.

All of these options are detailed in the <kbd>C-h f</kbd> help for the `use-package` macro, for further reference.

Comment: Indeed, and it is actually in the docstring, thanks for pointing me towards it. I wasn’t checking all the options I can pass to `use-package`, and `:demand` slipped my eye. Maybe it would worth it to update the `:bind` documentation so it tells you about this deferring.